EOFError: Ran out of input (using ribodetector)
I am new in python. I encountered an error when I used ribodetector.
The error was an the following:
ribodetector_cpu -t 20 `


-l 100 -i C:\Users\winst\Downloads\D0_2.cream.R1.001.fq.gz C:\Users\winst\Downloads\D0_2.cream.R2.001.fq.gz
-e rrna --chunk_size 100
-o C:\Users\winst\Downloads\D0reads.nonrrna.1.fq C:\Users\winst\Downloads\D0reads.nonrrna.2.fq
2024-04-24 00:07:24 : INFO  Using high MCC model file: C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ribodetector\data/ribodetector_600k_variable_len70_101_epoch47.onnx on CPU
2024-04-24 00:07:24 : INFO  Classify reads with chunk size 100
2024-04-24 00:07:24 : INFO  Writing output non-rRNA sequences into file: C:\Users\winst\Downloads\D0reads.nonrrna.1.fq, C:\Users\winst\Downloads\D0reads.nonrrna.2.fq
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in run_code
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Scripts\ribodetector_cpu.exe_main.py", line 7, in 
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ribodetector\detect_cpu.py", line 748, in main
seq_pred.detect()
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ribodetector\detect_cpu.py", line 526, in detect
self.run_with_chunks()
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ribodetector\detect_cpu.py", line 355, in run_with_chunks
p.start()
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 95, in init
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.InferenceSession' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\winst\anaconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: Ran out of input


Please help me to solve the error,
Thank you
I have tried to change the usage of CPU to 1, but it failed according to chatgpt's suggestion.
